# Session is not destroyed even if i have deleted all session files

Tags: php, session

I want to understand session functionality, using File System as storage and cookies.

I have deleted all session files from server directory **/var/lib/php5**

But when i refresh my page some files is again created for current user session.

I want to know the reason, why its not destroying current user session.

***SESSION ID IS CHANGING AFTER THIS ACTION****

Please Help.

Thanks

Comment: You probably have deleted wrong ones... Check php.ini session_handler

Comment: I have set file system as session handler which is also default one, and have checked session data path using session_save_path () function.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call session_destroy(); function to destroy

reference https://www.php.net/session_destroy

Comment: thanks for answer i know this, but i just want to know why deletion of session data files is not destroying session or how its getting data for current id?

Answer (score 0):

Always first **unset** the session variables then **destroy** them.